# Clean, Sync, Rebuld not working in Android Studio missing R

Tags: android

I have a problem on missing "R" in my android studio, I tried Sync, Clean and Rebuild still it is not working, and I located the R file in its path i have a file like this not_namespaced_r_class_sources and I don't know what's the problem cause it doesn't give errors in the logcat.

Comment: Try updating android studio. I had same problem and that fixed it.

Comment: try using invalid cache/restart.